# leave out blanks in SUMIFS excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In the above example, using sumifs, the sum of D comes as 0. But since there is no value for D, the result should be blank.

Using this formula does not help.

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$12,$B$2:$B$12,"<>",$A$2:$A$12,D3)
```

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Check first with COUNTIF if all cells contaning D are blanks, then return blank, else do the sumif.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,D3,$B$2:$B$12,"<>")=0,"",SUMIF($A$2:$A$12,D3,$B$2:$B$12))`.

Comment: HI, Vbasic2008.... this formula worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$12;D2)=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12;D2;$B$2:$B$12;"");"";SUMIFS($B$2:$B$12;$A$2:$A$12;D2))
```

With commas:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$12,D2)=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,D2,$B$2:$B$12,""),"",SUMIFS($B$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12,D2))
```

Comment: Hi Foxfire, I am not sure about the semicolons in the formula. However, overall it looks like the same logic VBasic2008 shared in the comment. Marking yours as answer on that assumption.

Comment: @user3471438 The semicolons just depend on your Excel settings. Many european countries use semicolon as argument separator in Excel instead of comma. Anyways, I've added the coma version of the formula.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

If you have EXCEL 365 you can use the FILTER function:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(tblData[count],(tblData[stat]=D3)*(tblData[count]<>""),"")),"no values")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ike, it is desktop application. But thanks for sharing how it happens on 365!